# Is there a minimalistic graph database?

Tags: graph, neo4j, storage, graph-databases, database-engine

I am looking for a very basic graph database engine. I only know of Neo4j so far.

For my application, nodes are only represented by their string names. They have no further attributes. Connections have start and end nodes and weights. They have no names associated with them.

The scientific name for the type of graph I want to store is *directed single-relation graph*.

Is there a graph database engine that provide high performance in my case? A REST or .NET interface would be great.

Comment: Does it have to be a graph database? db4o isa nice object database that can handle the scenario you describe nicely: http://community.versant.com

Comment: Yes it have to be. If not I _could_ also use relational MySql but I need the query speed for e.g. _friend of a friend_.

Comment: In that case an object database can also be a fit. It's designed to handle complex relationships with a better performance than relational dbs (eg. friends of friends)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave Neo4j a try, but it was too slow for importing my 30GB of data, even using the batch importer.

Because I don't need to access the data partly, I decided to use simple XML files for storage and implement all computations manually and in memory.

Answer (score 1):

http://neo4j.org/ should be quite minimalistic in its default config? For the REST minimalistic setup, you could use the server and run via http://hg.readify.net/neo4jclient/wiki/Home